# My worth's never none

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry, limerick

> Melodically speaking, my worth's never none;
>   Proportionally speaking, I'm a downer if under one;
>   I'm wont to overlap;
>   Or get up in a snap;
>   But when I am used, I hope it's not for a ton.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Scale

Melodically speaking, my worth's never none;

> A musical scale is  any set of musical notes ordered by fundamental frequency or pitch. Practising scales is a fundamental part of learning a musical instrument and is never worthless.

Proportionally speaking, I'm a downer if under one;

> A scale is a representation in proportional dimensions of one object to another usually represented as a ratio or fraction. If this ratio or fraction is smaller than one, we are looking at a downsized version of the original object.

I'm wont to overlap;

> Scales are plates protecting the skin of fish and reptiles which tend to overlap.

Or get up in a snap;

> Scale also means to climb

But when I am used, I hope it's not for a ton.

> A scale is an instrument for weighing. Usually this is for small amounts so most scales would not cope well with a ton of weight.

Answer (score 5):

> times

Melodically speaking, my worth's never none;

> the "time" in music is a description of number of notes per stanza, and never zero

Proportionally speaking, I'm a downer if under one;

> in the positive numbers, any number "times" a number below 1 is reduced.

I'm wont to overlap;

> times of events often overlap

Or get up in a snap;

> Times up!

But when I am used, I hope it's not for a ton.

> It's happened "a ton of times" - grammar we might prefer not to see.

Comment: Ultimately not what I was thinking, but an entirely reasonable alternative. If the intended answer doesn't come through, I'll accept this one! +1